# In Outlook, how can I split the same email on the same monitor?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I need read distant parts of a lengthy email chain simultaneously.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for asking this question. I’m forced to use Outlook at work, and by finding this answer I now learned something that will come in handy.

1. Double-click the message to open it in a separate window.
2. From the File tab, select `Options`
3. Select `Quick Access Toolbar`
4. From the drop-down `Choose commands from:`, select the entry `Commands Not in the Ribbon`
5. Scroll down and select `Split`, and click `Add >>`
6. Click OK

You now have an icon in the Quick Access Toolbar that will split the message window similar to Word and Excel.

[image: Quick Access Toolbar with the Split icon added]

Source: https://www.bettercloud.com/monitor/the-academy/split-message-window-outlook/

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to copy the entire mail in to a Word document, and use the View → Split option in Word.

I couldn't find a Split option in Outlook, but since you have multiple monitors, you could configure them *below* each other, rather than next to each other. To do that, right click on the desktop, select *Screen resolution* to open the configuration screen. Drag the monitors to the desired locations (as 1 and 2 in the screenshot below). Now you can increase the height of the mail window by dragging, or double clicking its top edge (Maximizing it will only occupy a single screen).

Mouse movement may be awkward when moving from one window to the other though.

[image: Screen resolution configuration]