# How can I launch three windows of the same email, one each for my 3 monitors?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Instead of the ['Split' function](https://superuser.com/q/1273019/269574), I prefer reading distant parts of a lengthy email chain emails simultaneously, by opening the same email chain thrice, with one window per monitor.

But no second window emerges, when I double-click on the email the second time (after the first double-clicking that caused the email to emerge in the first window).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid Outlook itself doesn't provide such an option to open the same message multiple times simultaneously. If you occasionally come across this situation, you may consider to open the message and save the message as .msg files to your desktop, then open the .msg files to your other monitors.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried opening Outlook in a new window:

[image: Have you tried opening Outlook in a new window?]